# Stability: orbits spiralling monotonically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm working my way through *Dynamics and Bifurcations* [Jack K. Hale, Huseyin Kocak] and I can't understand this probably trivial implication in Example 11.1 (page 334). We have a following system of ODEs (perturbed harmonic oscillator)
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_1 & = x_2 + a x_1 (x_1^2 + x_2^2), \\
\dot{x}_2 & = -x_1 + a x_2 (x_1^2 + x_2^2),
\end{aligned}
$a\in\mathbb{R}$, which in polar coordinates
\begin{equation}
x_1 = r \cos \theta, \quad x_2 = -r \sin \theta,
\end{equation}
reads
\begin{aligned}
\dot{r} & = a r^3, \\
\dot{\theta} & = 1.  
\end{aligned}
The book says: *"Since $\dot{\theta}>0$, the orbits spiral monotonically in $\theta$ around the origin. Therefore, the stability type of the origin of [the original planar system] is the same as that of the equilibrium point of the radial equation $\dot{r} = a r$."*

I fail to see why it matters whether $\theta$ is a monotonic function of $t$ or not. Can't we draw the same conclusion that the radial equation determines the stability of the origin when this condition does not hold? (Let's say $\dot{\theta} = \sin\theta$?)

Comment: Well, I fail to see too. Maybe it was confusing wording. The equation for $\theta$ has no effect on stability here.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dot\theta = 1$, you can integrate (assuming $t_0=0$) so
$$
\theta(t)=t-t_0
$$
which means the angle is increasing (note that you could also conclude this if $\dot \theta >0, \forall t$). This means that the stability of the orbits depends only if the radius increase or decrease (that is, on the signal of $a$).